# PHP Countdown Timer mistake

Tags: php, date, time, timer, countdown

Well the problem is when time gets to 23h.00m it glitches and counts 1 hour until 00h.00m and then again works fine.
Can I stop timer from 23h:00m - 00h:00m and then start again?
Or after 23.00 make it go again from 23h.59m.59s?

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Tallinn');
$now = new DateTime();

$future_date = new DateTime('23:00:00');

$interval = $future_date->diff($now);

echo $interval->format("%h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you could do:
check when the date (now) is greater than the future date, and if so, add one day to that future date

Code:

```
$now = new DateTime();

$future_date = new DateTime('23:00:00');
if ($now > $future_date) {
    $future_date->modify('+1 day');
}

$interval = $future_date->diff($now, false);
echo $interval->format("%h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds");
```

Comment: Works fine. I'm learning php myself and only this web and users like you make it enjoyable. Thanks you so much.